# Can $a^2 - 2^b$ be factored if $b$ is odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, factoring, integers

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers.

If $b$ is even (i.e. $b=2c$ for some positive integer $c$), then $a^2 - 2^b$ can be factored as
$$a^2 - 2^b = a^2 - 2^{2c} = (a + 2^c)(a - 2^c).$$

**Edited: (October 2, 2021 - 4:18 PM Manila time)** I would have to qualify that I am only interested in those $a$ such that $a$ is **odd**.

Here is my question:

> What about if  $b$ is odd (i.e. $b=2d+1$ for some nonnegative integer $d$)?  Can $a^2 - 2^b$ still be factored?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $X = a^2 - 2^b$, and let $b=2d+1$ for some nonnegative integer $d$.

Then we obtain
$$X = a^2 - 2^{2d+1}$$
$$X - 2^{2d+1} = a^2 - 2^{2d+2} = (a + 2^{d+1})(a - 2^{d+1})$$
from which we finally get the expression
$$X = 2^{2d+1} + (a + 2^{d+1})(a - 2^{d+1}) = 2^b + (a + 2^{(b+1)/2})(a - 2^{(b+1)/2})$$
for $X$.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Comment: The possibility of a factorisation depends heavily on $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @MichaelHoppe!  I also know that $a$ is odd.  Including that information now in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we allow irrational coefficients, then it can be factored:
we have $$a^2-2^{2d+1}=a^2-(\sqrt2\cdot2^d)^2=(a-\sqrt2\cdot2^d)(a+\sqrt2\cdot2^d).$$
However, if we are a bit stricter, then it cannot be factored in terms of $a$ and $2^d$. Suppose that there are polynomials $P(a,2^d)$ and $Q(a,2^d)$ with integer coefficients such that $P(a,2^d)Q(a,2^d)=a^2-2^{2d+1}$. Then it follows that $P(x,y)Q(x,y)=x^2-2y^2$ for all $x,y$. But since $x^2-2y^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x,y]$, the only options are the trivial ones where one of $P$ and $Q$ is the constant polynomial $1$.

Comment: An upvote for now, @Riemann!  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So essentially, does your answer imply that
$$a^2 - 2^b = p$$
for *some integer prime* $p$, @Riemann?

Comment: That is not exactly what my answer states, but it is true: for $a=3$ and $b=1$ we have $a^2-2^b=9-2=7$ which is prime.

Comment: In general, when a polynomial is irreducible then it does not mean that it is prime at some value. For example, $P(x)=x^3-x-12$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$, but for all integers $x$ the value of $P(x)$ is composite.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the added explanation, @Riemann!  =)

Comment: Accepting your answer now, @Riemann!  Thanks again.  =)